# Open mail in Outlook, through URL. Using Exchange Webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to get a intranet page to open an mailitem in the Outlook client.

We are using Exchange Webservices(EWS), and communicating with an Exchange 2007 server.
What we have done so far, is to be able to read top 5 mailitems from an inbox, and displaying these on a webpage. What we would like to do is to get the list of mailitems to link directly into Outlook.

This means that when the user clicks a link to an email, Outlook should open, and open the specific mailitem.

We have registered the outlook protocol, and we have general links will open the Outlook client. By general links i mean outlook:inbox will open Outlook and open the inbox, and outlook:calendar will open Outlook and open the calendar.

From each mailitem, ive tried to call outlook:itemidtype.id, but this doesn't work.

Anyone got a clue on how to open the mailitem?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this myself, but Outlook uses the MAPI EntryId to locate an item. You can retrieve this value using an extended property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446027.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft documents the /f switch for command line access to a message, but helpfully fails to provide a real world example I can't get /f to work, and think it is broken.

Anyone have an example of this, instead of MS useless doc of "/f msgfilename"